Generate Bootstrap CSS from SCSS with vendors attributes
I have a problem generating CSS from SCSS files. As I'm not a frontend expert (I'm really a newbie) my question may be stupid but I have no idea.
So I've installed Bootstrap 5.1.3 (I know it's an outdated version) with:
npm install bootstrap@5.1.3
I've also configured Vite which comes with Laravel (so it was very easy) and for testing I've disabled minifying.
Then I've generated CSS with:
npm run build
After this step, I've compared the bootstrap 5.1.3 CSS file and the one I'v generated. Two files are mostly identical but there are some differences.
Here are a few differences:
Original
abbr[title],
abbr[data-bs-original-title] {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
  cursor: help;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}

…

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  font: inherit;
}

…

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #6c757d;
  opacity: 1;
}


Generated
abbr[title],
abbr[data-bs-original-title] {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
  cursor: help;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}

…

// Missing

…

// Missing


I just would like to generate a CSS file which would be the same as the one generated by the Bootstrap team itself.
Thank you
I've searched on different web forums and it seems there's (or there was) a config in bootstrap package' file but I don't find it in recent distributions and above all I cannot make it change my generated CSS.

I believe it's Vite targeting more recent browser than what Bootstrap does. You could probably change that in your vite config, see the docs.

Thank you @AmauryHanser, these are not the docs I was looking for but I think it's going to help me a lot
